# if switch not working

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to make a control that will block the user from entering a term year for their home loan that is over 30.

```
HomeLoan hLoan=new HomeLoan(name, custID, loanID);
System.out.println("You selected Home Loan");
System.out.println("Enter term: ");
term=input.nextInt();
boolean l=false;
boolean s = hLoan.termCorrect(term);
System.out.println(s);
if (s=true){
   System.out.println("Error: Maximum of 30 years");}
else {l=false;}
```

It calls a method that termCorrect() that determines if the term is over 30, and returns true or false.  When I run it, the value of s is correct for the input that I use, but it always run the error message for some reason, regardless of s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The message is always shown because you can always attribute the `true` value to `s` `(s=true)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=`:

```
if (s=true){
```

Use the comparison operator `==` instead:

```
if (s == true) {
```

or, because it's already a `boolean`, use `s` itself:

```
if (s)
```

The last form is preferable.  It's concise, and there's no chance to an operator confused with `=`.

Comment: +1, but maybe stress that `if(s)` is much preferable to `if(s == true)`.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment operator in if statement is invalid. Change from

```
  if (s=true){// this invalid
```

To

```
 if (s){
```

Comment: or equally s==true. +1

Comment: `if(s)` same as `if(s==true)`

Comment: If by "invalid" you mean "it doesn't do what you want" then that would be true. If by "invalid" you mean "doesn't compile" or "syntax error" that would be a different story.

Comment: @Masud I know, that's why i said, "equally"

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment. `==` is equality comparison.

Comment: `most things evaluate to boolean true` No, only `true` does (and true-valued `Boolean` objects, if you include autounboxing). `1`, `"true"`, `new MyTrueObject()` etc all don't evaluate to `true`. Java doesn't do weak typing. Try `if(1) {}`, and you'll see it doesn't compile.

Comment: Oops, ya, I was thinking Ruby

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. By using `s=true` you are setting `s` to true inside the `if`. The equality operator in Java is `==`. Therefore, you could do this:

```
if(s==true)
```

Or, since `s==true` is logically equivalent to `s` (think about it), you can do this:

```
if(s)
```